# Quiz algorithm by steps logic

Tags: php, jquery, php-5.3

Hello Stackoverflow Family, I'm trying to create a small quiz application for my website. I've created true/false and points questionnaire but the one I'm stuck with is something like [this](http://www.quizony.com/animalPersonality/index.html).

What is the logic of these types of quizzes?

I use php and jquery.

Comment: Your question is very vague, are you looking for an open-source quiz? Do you have a bug in developing your own quiz? Is this your website?

Comment: I just need to know the logic of that type of quiz. How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically start with a question, say:

do you have four legs?

If they answer yes, you've got an end point, dog. ask:

are you a dog?

If the answer is no. ask for a question which shows the difference between a dog and their answer, also what their answer is. so next time someone isn't a dog, ask them that question.

What are you?
a cat
Suggest a question to separate a cat from a dog?
"do you go miow?"

basically build up a tree of data, each question points to either a question on the 'yes' or 'no' action. or an end point, which is either "are you this?" or "so what are you?"

in theory, and it's not perfect, but it's pretty good, this will guide a user to the answer they're seeking if it's been put in before.

that's the logic, but I don't use PHP, so you'll have to work out how to implement it yourself.